# ¿Cómo añadir un valor actualizado en una variable dentro de un arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, controller

Estoy intentando poner un dato actualizado en una variable dentro de un ArrayList, por ejemplo, desde la base de datos me trae 3 variables, a="hola", b="123", c="stack", lo que deseo es cambiar la variable b y asignarle otro valor por ejemplo b="000";

```js
   ArrayList<ejemploDto> lista= new ArrayList();
    lista= ejemploDto.Listar_Datos();
                    int tamaño= lista.size();
                    for(int i=0; i < tamaño; i++){
                        ejemploDto ods = (ejemploDto) lista.get(i);
                      String fv =  ods.getVariable_a();
                        String fg = ods.getVariabele_b();
                        
                        ods.setVariable_a("123");
                
                        
                    }
```

Explicación, tengo un ArrayList que llama a un método "Listar_Datos()" en donde me trae un ArrayList con una lista de registros, extraigo el tamaño con el método size() y lo recorro en un for, desde ahí puedo acceder a cada variable y es ahí en donde le deseo agregar un nuevo valor pero no me funciona.

Pensaba que con ods.setVariable_a("123"); le seteaba el valor pero no. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias!!!

Comment: vos estas usando set en un "nuevo objeto" llamado ods dentro del bucle , pero en que momento  estas guardando ese "nuevo objeto" en el arrayList de la clase???

Comment: @Dramaturgo técnicamente no vendría siendo un nuevo objeto,  ese trozo de código lo único que hace es recorrer una lista, luego accede a cada uno de sus objetos, por ejemplo si son 3, en el primero accedo a sus atributos y luego le seteo un valor que yo desee a ese atributo existente (es como un update a un atributo). Por cierto ya funciona, tenía que darle un Clean and Build creo que la IDE estaba algo mareada.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debería funcionar pero deberías corregir algunas inconsistencias

#### 1.Nombre de variables

No deberías usar caracteres especiales dentro del nombre de variables, acostúmbrate a nombrar en ingles, ya que es un idioma universal

```
//malo
int tamaño= lista.size(); 
//bueno
int listSize = lista.size();
```

#### 2. Recorrido de lista

hay formas más modernas de recorrer una lista que usando un for con indice(index), un ejemplo seria este, la iteracion se hace de manera automatica en base al tamaño de tu lista y ya no necesitas ni obtener el tamaño de la lista;

```
for(Integer number:lista){
   //Lo que haces en cada iteracion
}
```

Integer -> es el tipo de variable que contiene tu lista

number -> es un nombre de como quieres llamar a tu objeto que estas iterando

lista -> Ya es obvio jeje.

#### 3. Resultado final

```
ArrayList<ejemploDto> lista= new ArrayList();
lista= ejemploDto.Listar_Datos();

for(ejemploDto dto:lista)             
   dto.setVariable_a("123");                
}
```

*Ojo: en tu bucle que haz proporcionado se esta actualizando el valor para todos los objetos dentro de tu lista, si deseas que solo se modifique el objeto que tu deseas, debes añadir una condicional antes de hacer el cambio.*

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias por tu tiempo, el código estaba bien solo tenía que darle un Clean and Build, tomaré en cuenta utilizar ese foreach para mejorar el código. Gracias!!!